# how to create consecutive backslash in octopress with kramdown

Tags: html, markdown, octopress

I'm using Kramdown and Octopress to write markdown text, but I don't know how to get `\\` in html. I tried `\\\\` but get `&#92;`. According to its doc, `\` is used for escape. Does anyone know how to get `\\` in html, not `&#92;&#92;`? thanks. And I'm confused about when `\\` will be translated into `\` and when will be `<br />`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with Kramdown, but with a plugin that comes with Octopress called rubypants.rb. Take a look at plugins/rubypants.rb, and you will find a method named process_escapes which does several calls to str.gsub. (Line 335 or so.) One of these replaces the double backslash ("\") with the escape code you're seeing - fix that line and you'll be good. (You can fix it by moving the 'str.' to the next gsub and deleting the rest of the line.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the problem here

```sh
$ kramdown --version
0.14.2

$ kramdown <<< '\\\\'
<p>\\</p>
```